# Finding img src of parent of parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Recently I've been attempting to web scrape an image from a website with cheerio but I'm having issues actually finding it. Currently I'm looping through each link within the page and then attempting to find the image from the parents of the link.

Here is my current code:

```
$('a').each(function (Index, Element) {
    if (Index <= 8) {
        let Link = $(Element).attr('href'); 
        let Main = $(Element).parent().parent().find("img").attr("src")
        console.log(Main)
        PlayersEmbed.addField(ConvertNumber(Index), "Test", true);
    }
})
```

Here is website HTML:

https://smashdata.gg/error/smash/ultimate/player/Bravo?id=0
[image]

Comment: You say you're having an issue. What's the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to actually find the src. I'm just getting returned undefined.

Comment: You may get better results with `$('tr a')`. Regardless, some of the rows just don't have images.

Comment: You can do `$(a).closest('td').next().find('img')`, but yes it makes more sense to iterate those trs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out myself by searching for "tr" instead like how @Ouroborus suggested.

Comment: If you want this to be a more meaningful answer for others to reference, then please show your actual solution in code.